# Google Map inflate exception in binary XML file

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps, android-fragments

I'm developing an android app using Google Maps.
My Maps fragment was working just fine but after i set a design for my app i have this error just in my Maps Fragment:

```
08-09 19:59:37.982: E/AndroidRuntime(14374): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 08-09  
19:59:37.982: E/AndroidRuntime(14374): Process: pixels.myapp, PID: 14374 08-    
09 19:59:37.982: E/AndroidRuntime(14374): android.view.InflateException:       
Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment 08-09 19:59:37.982: 
E/AndroidRuntime(14374):    at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:720) 08-09          
19:59:37.982: E/AndroidRuntime(14374):  at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:470) 08-09 
19:59:37.982: E/AndroidRuntime(14374):  at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 08-09 
19:59:37.982: E/AndroidRuntime(14374):  at 
pixels.myapp.FragmentMaps.onCreateView(FragmentMaps.java:70) 08-09 
19:59:37.982: E/AndroidRuntime(14374):  at 
android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700) 08-09 
19:59:37.982: E/AndroidRuntime(14374):  at 
android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890) 08-09 
19:59:37.982: E/AndroidRuntime(14374):  at 
android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1040) 08-09 
19:59:37.982: E/AndroidRuntime(14374):  at 
android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4870) 08-09 19:59:37.982: 
E/AndroidRuntime(14374):    at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 08-09  
19:59:37.982: E/AndroidRuntime(14374):  at  
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:470) 08-09 
19:59:37.982: E/AndroidRuntime(14374):  at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 08-09 
19:59:37.982: E/AndroidRuntime(14374):  at 
pixels.myapp.FragmentMaps.onCreateView(FragmentMaps.java:70) 08-09 
19:59:37.982: E/AndroidRuntime(14374):  at  
android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700) 08-09 
19:59:37.982: E/AndroidRuntime(14374):  at 
android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890) 08-09 
19:59:37.982: E/AndroidRuntime(14374):  at 
android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062) 08-09
19:59:37.982: E/AndroidRuntime(14374):  at
android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684) 08-09   
19:59:37.982: 
E/AndroidRuntime(14374):    at 
android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447) 
08-09 19:59:37.982: E/AndroidRuntime(14374):    at 
android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443) 08-09 
19:59:37.982: E/AndroidRuntime(14374):  at 
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 08-09 19:59:37.982: 
E/AndroidRuntime(14374):    at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 08-09 19:59:37.982: 
E/AndroidRuntime(14374):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 08-09 
19:59:37.982: E/AndroidRuntime(14374):  at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5426) 08-09  
19:59:37.982: 
E/AndroidRuntime(14374):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native 
Method) 08-09 19:59:37.982: E/AndroidRuntime(14374):    at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 08-09 19:59:37.982: 
E/AndroidRuntime(14374):    at

com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
(ZygoteInit.java:1268
) 08-09 19:59:37.982: E/AndroidRuntime(14374):  at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084) 08-09  
19:59:37.982: E/AndroidRuntime(14374):  at 
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 08-09 19:59:37.982: 
E/AndroidRuntime(14374): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Binary XML file line #2: Duplicate id 0x7f0c0093, tag null, or parent id 
0x7f0c0026 with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment 
08-09 19:59:37.982: E/AndroidRuntime(14374):    at 
android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4856) 08-09 19:59:37.982: 
E/AndroidRuntime(14374):    at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
```

and the MapFragment.xml:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
```

and the MapFragment.java:

```
public class FragmentMaps extends Fragment implements OnMarkerClickListener {
private GoogleMap googleMap;
MapView mMapView;
ArrayList<LatLng> markerPoints;
private Polyline line;

public FragmentMaps() {

}



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maps,container, false);
    markerPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    markerPoints.add(new LatLng(35.8400065, 10.5990825));
    markerPoints.add(new LatLng(35.8400030, 10.5990825));


    mMapView= (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.map);
    mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mMapView.onResume();

    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    googleMap = mMapView.getMap();
    // latitude and longitude

    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);

    /**googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
            // Already two locations
            if(markerPoints.size()>1){
                markerPoints.clear();
                googleMap.clear();
            }

            // Adding new item to the ArrayList
            markerPoints.add(point);

            // Creating MarkerOptions
            MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();

            // Setting the position of the marker
            options.position(point);

            /**
     * For the start location, the color of marker is GREEN and
     * for the end location, the color of marker is RED.

            if(markerPoints.size()==1){
                options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
            }else if(markerPoints.size()==2){
                options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
            }

            // Add new marker to the Google Map Android API V2
            googleMap.addMarker(options);

            // Checks, whether start and end locations are captured
            if(markerPoints.size() >= 2){
                LatLng origin = markerPoints.get(0);
                LatLng dest = markerPoints.get(1);

                // Getting URL to the Google Directions API
                String url = getDirectionsUrl(origin, dest);

                DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

                // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
                downloadTask.execute(url);

            }
        }
    }
            );

     **/




    double latitude = 35.8400065;

    double longitude = 10.5990825;

    // create marker
    MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
            new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("JetSet Café");



    // Changing marker icon
    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE));

    // adding marker
    googleMap.addMarker(marker);

    marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
            new LatLng(35.835829, 10.5957462)).title("ToscanaVilla Café");

    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
    googleMap.addMarker(marker);
    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
    .target(new LatLng(latitude,longitude)).zoom(12).build();

    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
            .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
    return rootView;
}
```

As i said before after i set the design for my app everything was just ok, but after that i can t get mu map fragment works.

Comment: there is that `Duplicate id 0x7f0c0093`. you can see in R.java which id that is.

Comment: that's the map id in the XML file but it s not duplicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just add this layout and it worked fine :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:id="@+id/map"
         android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I tried to add the following layout but i get an error : CastExecption 08-14 17:49:58.433: E/AndroidRuntime(5009): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
08-14 17:49:58.433: E/AndroidRuntime(5009):  at pixels.myapp.FragmentMaps.onCreateView(FragmentMaps.java:76)